# 'Yes' button is not shown in confirmation box in Android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

hi friends i set a dialog box with yes and no button but only NO is visible YES button is not visible please suggest me

This is the code i used thanks in advance

```
     alertDialog.setButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                 // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });

             // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setButton("NO bad", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 dialog.cancel();
                 }
             });
```

Comment: If this is really an `AlertDialog`, use the positive and negative buttons.

Comment: it shows an error if i use positive and negative

Comment: the method is undefined for the type AlertDialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should follow this Builder pattern example given below.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setTitle(titleResourceId)
        .setMessage(messageResourceId)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeToast(mContext, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeToast(mContext, "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    builder.show();
```

Using `setPositiveButton()` and `setNegativeButton()` allows android to place the buttons in the correct order according to the platform the app runs in.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
alertDialog.setButton
```

use

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton
alertDialog.setNegativeButton
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
setButton()
```

Use `setPositiveButton()` for "Yes" and `setNegativeButton()` for "No"